# how to make a card on middle of body on flutter

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, dart

So i have an error that i wanted to make card that stack on my background  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4psa.jpg), but eventually it not working it just showing blank screen
Heres the code that im writted
Thanks Before!

```
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(90, 30, 0, 0),
                              child: Text(
                                'Profile',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 35,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

```
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 20),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SvgPicture.network(
                            'https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/5/Profile-Male-PNG.png',
                            height: 40,
                          )
                        ],
```

Comment: Can you share the entire build method? It's difficult to read the way you've posted it.

Comment: i cant post all detail code its showing an error when i want to post it

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PEjGcTH maybe you can look at this images, i make those card as comment so i can look on my phone

Comment: For a start, your background container is overflowing the bounds. Comment out line 19 (where you set the height) and see if that changes anything. Also, what errors are you getting in the console when you run the app?

Comment: it does not showing any error on the debug console but when i try to run it, it throwing to convert_patch.dart

Comment: When you say debug console, are you referring to a web console or the terminal that you're running `flutter run` from?

Comment: oh sorry i mean terminal console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237844/discussion-between-alex-meuer-and-imam-rizky-ganteng).

Answer (score 1):

You are using SVG package to load a PNG,
use Image package for PNG images, also to the Stack like the image you mentioned to have custom border-radius, here is the code using decorated Container:

```
     Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: Image.network(
                'https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/5/Profile-Male-PNG.png',
                height: 100,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: Text(
                'Profile',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 35,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: it still making a blank screen on my phone when i run it but when i make the code as a comment it run smooth, u can check on this images https://imgur.com/a/PEjGcTH, i cant show u all the code on this post because it got error "your code are looks mosty likely".

Comment: Have the complete code snippet in the question, so I can test it.